# training VGG16 from scratch using keras function api. all test images gets predicted as one class

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

i was training CNN based on VGG16 architecture using functional api.
Data set had 2 class(car & aero-plane) each with 500 images for training and 100 images for validation. i am not getting good results. and also while prediction it classifies all images as one class( if i will give car image it will o/p as aero plane)
please help me in getting correct output. help me in correcting my concept

```
import keras
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D , Flatten
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing import image
```

loading dataset

```
batch_size=32
trdata = ImageDataGenerator(zoom_range=0.3, rotation_range=50,rescale=1/255,
                                   width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, #shear_range=0.2, 
                                   horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode='nearest')
traindata = trdata.flow_from_directory(directory="train",batch_size=batch_size,target_size=(224,224),class_mode='categorical')
tsdata = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
validdata = tsdata.flow_from_directory(directory="validation",batch_size=batch_size, target_size=(224,224),class_mode='categorical')
```

defining architecture

```
image_shape=(224,224,3)
l1=Input(shape=image_shape)
l2 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l1)
l3 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l2)
l4 = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))(l3)
l5 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l4)
l6 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l5)
l7 = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))(l6)
l8 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l7)
l9 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l8)
l10 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l9)
l11 = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))(l10)
l12 = Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l11)
l13 = Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l12)
l15 = Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l13)
l16 = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))(l15)
l17 = Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l16)
l18 = Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l17)
l19 = Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(l18)
l20 = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))(l19)
fc1=keras.layers.Flatten()(l20)
fc11=Dense(4096, activation='relu')(fc1)
fc12=Dense(4096, activation='relu')(fc11)
fc13=Dense(2, activation='softmax')(fc12)
model1 = Model(inputs=l1, outputs=fc13)
model1.summary()
```

model compiling and training

```
opt = optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model1.fit_generator(
      traindata,
      steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(traindata.samples//batch_size),
      epochs=5,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data = validdata,
      validation_steps=math.ceil(validdata.samples//batch_size))
```

making prediction

```
uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
 
  # predicting images
  path = '/content/' + fn
  img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(224, 224))
  img = np.asarray(img)
  plt.imshow(img)
  img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
  classes = model.predict(img/255)
  a=classes[0]
  pos=np.argmax(a)
  if pos==0:
    print("plane")
  elif pos==1:
    print("car")
```

accuracy
[image]
loss
[image]

output

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just look at your training accuracy curve, it's almost flat 50%. For a 2 class classification, even a random guess would show 50% accuracy.

So, your model is not learning anything at all. There is more than one issue with your approach.

1. 500 images for training! That is never a good number of samples for training a deep learning model, so increase the number of samples.
2. Decrease the learning rate.
3. For softmax output, your loss should be categorical cross-entropy. Just simply add 1 neuron at the end with sigmoid and binary cross entropy loss.